# Rewriting urls with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a url but I can't seem to make it happen.

I just want one working example so I can move on to all pages of my website.

So I have this link:

```
www.domain.com/article.php?id=1
```

And I can to change it to:

```
www.domain.com/article/1/
```

That's ok for now, later I'll replace the number with the article title.

This is what I have on my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^article\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$    article/$1/
```

What is wrong it it? I heard that the .htaccess file needs to be in ASCII if using FTP to save in on the server but I don't know how to do it since I created it by myself.

Comment: You are doing this backwards, quite literally.

Comment: RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ /article.php?id=$1

Comment: The syntax is `RewriteRule (IncomingPath.*) LocalPath?$1`

Comment: oh... lol my mistake xD but nothing happens :S

Comment: had my plus sign in the wrong spot, edited. code works :p

Comment: still nothing... I think that I have a problem with my .htaccess or with my server...

Comment: ensure AllowOverride All is enabled on the directory (apache config)

Comment: How do I do that? Can I do it by FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` in a condition:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule    ^article\.php$    article/%1/? [L]
```

This internally rewrites your request to `/article/1/`. The browser will still see the old URL.

What you are more likely looking for is to match against the request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+article\.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but nothing happens... ? :(

Comment: the seconds code works, the first does not work. Still, using the seconds code I get a 404 page...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that mistake and I corrected it yet it gives me a 404 error page.

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 when you go to `/article.php?id=1`, do you get a 404?

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 or is everything really `/articles?id=1` like in your example?

Comment: no, the pages works as expected. Here is one page of my website: http://wordicious.com/article.php?id=60

Comment: +1 As this answer definitely doesn't deserve -1, moreover there is no comment as a reason for down-vote.

Comment: Sorry @JonLin I made a big mistake. I corrected the above link. What I have is www.domain.com/article.php?id=1

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 I'm going to take a guess and say you probably have multiviews turned on, try turning that off by adding this line: `Options -Multiviews`

Comment: I don't know where to add it yet I added after and before "RewriteEngine On" but the result is the same, I get a 404 page.

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 do you have another line in your htaccess file that starts with `Options`? You can combine them all (and make sure there isn't one turning multiviews on)

Comment: I don't have anything written besides your code. Or I have another htaccess somewhere else and I don't know but the probabilities are almost none because I looked on the root directory and on public_html where I have my website files. By the way, the htaccess is on the root directory, I'll try to move it to public_html

Comment: It is now working after I moved it to public_html directory. There is still a problem, css is not being loaded.

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 You need to change all your links to absolute URLs or add `<base href="/" />` to your page header

Comment: Nice! Now I just need to learn A LOT MORE about this so I can make all url's like this one :) Is it hard to send, for example, the article title from the page to the url? Imagine that I want the title instead of the number.

Comment: I already know how to solve my previous question :) I just want to know the following: I already have urls typed on the document, will I need to change all links, file by file?

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 you mean `/article.php` -> `/article` and `/something.php` to `/something`? Depends on how many you have and if there's anything else besides those files in your document root.

Comment: There are many php files but others (js,css,etc) are inside folders. Is there a way to change them all? Plus, can I change urls to clean ones on ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this backwards, quite literally.

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ /article.php?id=$1
```